# How do I control my collection/object rotation after applying align euler to vector?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, constraints

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to make a cake with mini strawberries sticking on the sides around the cake. So far, I got them to the position I want them to be, but I'm having trouble controlling the rotation of them. As you can see, each mini strawberry seems to have a random rotation. I'm using Sample Nearest Surface and Align Euler to Vector to get the mini strawberries to orient them correctly onto the surfaces of the cake base.

What can I do to have more control over their rotation? For example, how do I make them all the same rotation? Or how can I make their rotation random within a determined range?

Attached an image of the node tree I'm using.[image]

Comment: Use 2nd Align Euler, example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/306540/60486

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hi Markus! Thanks so much for your reply. This seems to be the right solution but I don't know how to apply it with confidence. This is my first time using geometry nodes so I haven't fully grasped the significance of the different ones in your example yet. For now, I tried adding a 2nd Align Euler and it worked to make the orientation the same. However, I'm not fully sure what I did and how to manipulate the rotation further. Again, thanks so much! I appreciate your response and the thorough answers you provided in the other posts :)

Comment: Check out also the "Rotate Euler" node, you might want to rotate it in local mode around one of the axis (probably around local $z$ axis)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be restricted to geometry nodes: For a use case like this (scattering objects above a surface with equal/random/controllable rotation) I strongly recommend the free Blender Add-on [Gscatter](https://www.graswald3d.com/gscatter) which has plenty of tutorials on YouTube (by the [creator](https://www.youtube.com/@Graswald)). Gscatter uses Geometry Nodes under the hood.